# Add PostSharp Aspect to System.IO namespace?

Tags: postsharp

I am looking to add my aspect to the system.io namespace, I already searches lots of solutions which didn't do the trick but basically I want to handle exceptions and do some logging on the File class from System.IO namespace. Just like adding [MyAspect] to the top of the class..

Is there a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider aspect like this:

```
[PSerializable]
public class MyAspect : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
    }
}
```

You can apply this aspect to any 3rd assembly called from your project by applying `MyAspect`:

```
[assembly: MyAspect(AttributeTargetAssemblies = "mscorlib", AttributeTargetTypes = "System.IO.*")]
```

When you specify this assembly attribute then PostSharp decorates all calls from your project to methods from `System.IO` namespace in `mscorlib` assembly with `MyAspect`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i tried this couple days ago. it Works! Do you know how i could affect the WHOLE system namespace but exclude the Console class?

Comment: I found out how to do that using AttributeExclude = true and using AttributePriority but im still left with a stackoverflow exception like my aspect is being added to itself or something.. Time for a new question.